How to repair peeling off paint and stucco
Could someone be so kind and tell me how (if possible) to fix this mess? I'm at my wits' end. All I wanted to do was to fix a crack in the stucco, but it turned out there are many paint bubbles and stucco itself is falling off in thin layers under them.
Is it possible to fix it or the only solution is siding?  
If yes, how to peel off failing pieces quicker?
Should I use some penetrating sealant?
Should I use stucco mix to apply where it failed?
Should I use primer before painting?
What to put in the gap between stucco and bricks? And also between window trim and stucco? 
Should I seal the bottom of the stucco where the wood is visible? 
I'm trying to find info online, but getting only more lost with all the caulk and sealant options.
Thank you in advance!
